# Using python to define a matrix of byte data

Tags: python

I have this data in a file:

```
00 00 1a 00 2f 48 00 00  88 9f 5d 04 00 00 00 00   
10 04 a8 09 a0 00 c8 00  00 00 80 00 00 00 ff ff   
ff ff ff ff 00 25 9c 8f  d5 bf 00 25 9c 8f d5 bf   
40 7f 04 30 bc 61 02 00  00 00 64 00 21 04 00 05   
54 49 52 41 44 01 04 82  84 8b 96 03 01 0d 05 04   
00 01 00 00 20 01 00 2a  01 00 32 08 0c 12 18 24   
30 48 60 6c dd 18 00 50  f2 02 01 01 03 00 03 a4   
00 00 27 a4 00 00 42 43  5e 00 62 32 2f 00 dd 05   
00 50 f2 05 00 dd 0e 00  50 f2 04 10 4a 00 01 10   
10 44 00 01 02 dd 05 00  09 86 01 00 fe 66 cf c2
```

and I would like, using python, to define a matrix with 16 columns and 10 rows with the data in file.

Note for example that `ff` or `40` represent 1 byte.

Comment: Is the file binary or hex/ascii (If you open it with text-editor, do you see the "00 00 1a" or some "gibrish"?

Comment: with text editor i see 00 00 1a

Answer (score 0):

somehting like this?

```
data = ''
with open ("in.txt", "r") as in_file:
    data = in_file.read().split(' ')
with open ("out.txt", "w") as out_file:
    position = 0
    for i in data:
        if 0 == (position % 16):
            out_file.write ("\r\n") #next line windows style.  for unix it should be \n
        out_file.write ("%s " % i)
        position += 1
```

Comment: when i excecut that in a python file from my terminal (using ubuntu)

Comment: i have a problem, it's not clear for me this method.

Comment: What is the problem?  change the "in.txt" to your input file, and the "out.txt" to your output file.  Had I missed anything?